# Browser history strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, browser-history

For my PHP based Ajax heavy project I'm using

```
history.pushState({}, '', newUrl);
```

to change url in adressbar.

But this disables forward and backward buttons of browsers. When I backward url changes in adressbar but nothing happen. It's okay if it will not ajax load but just redirect to previous url (with page refresh). I don't need complex popstate or other thing.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: It is your job to _make_ things happen – that’s what the `popstate` event is for, so that you you know when the user uses the back/forward buttons, and your script can react to it, by displaying the appropriate content again.

Comment: Pushing and Popping: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/ a useful read to understand the history api.